# Decimal point calculation, python I'd like to calculate up to 20 decimal places

Tags: python

I'd like to calculate up to 20 decimal places.
the answer I want 0.60000000000000000000
My answer 0.59999999999999997780
How do I solve this?
my code

```
  a,b=map(float,input().split())
  print("%.20f"%(a/b))
```

Comment: `decimal` module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Comment: `"%.20f"` is just an output formatting instruction. It does not affect the calculation.

Comment: updated the answer use right padding

Answer (score 0):

```
print('{:<020}'.format(0.6));
```

use format , and right padding

```
 print('{:<020}'.format(a/b));
```

So for your case you can use :

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 20

result = ("{:.20f}".format(Decimal("0.6")))
print(result)
```

or

```
result=5/4 #add a/b here
formatedResult = ('{:<0'+str((len(str(float(result)).split('.')[0])+21))+'}').format(float(result))
print("The formated result: " + formatedResult)
print("Length of digit after decimal point: "+str(len(formatedResult.split('.')[1])))
```

Here we find number of characters before the decimal point and add 21 to it (including the decimal character)

Comment: @superbrain please try that !!!!!!!!!!! rounding the answer will become 6 and then using %.20f for 6 prints 6 with 20 zeros

Comment: @superbrain did you downvote ? If someone else downvoted please leave a comment and explain why so it would helpful for others

Comment: Looks better, though it's missing two zeros. And for 12.6 it's missing *three* zeros. And for 1/7 it ends with a 0 instead of a 7 (granted, that's partly the fault of the inaccurate calculation, but the OP does talk about the calculation, not just the printing, so they might want the correct digit there).

Comment: @superbrain updated the answer thanks for pointting that out see the updated answer